# How to debug nodejs addon by gdb

Tags: c++, node.js, macos

### Heading

I am writing a Node.Js C++ addon,When I try to debug my c++ add by the way i searched on internet,it just cannt work at all.

what i get from internet is 
gdb node
set args app.js
run

i get this
/usr/local/bin/node": not in executable format: File format not recognized

after type file /usr/local/bin/node

i get this 
/usr/local/bin/node: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/bin/node (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/local/bin/node (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

i dont konw why my gdb told me the node is not a executeable fomat

Answer (score 7):

Did you build node.js with debugging enabled? It looks like you are on a mac, if you used homebrew to install mode, try the following:

```
brew install nodejs --with-debug
```

Then try:

```
gdb --args /usr/local/bin/node app.js
```

Also gdb on the mac has been deprecated in favor of lldb so you might try lldb as well:

```
lldb -- /usr/local/bin/node app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a VSCode user, you may find this helpful.

Basic steps are:

1. Install the vscode plugin https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb
2. Setup your launch.json to look like this :

`{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
     "type": "lldb",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Program",
     "program": "/absolute/path/to/node",
     "args": [
        "/absolute/path/to/your/index.js"
     ]
  }]
}`

Then setup breakpoints as you would in VS Code.

Happy debugging!

I have also published a detailed blog here if you want more detailed explanation.

https://medium.com/@atulanand94/debugging-nodejs-c-addons-using-vs-code-27e9940fc3ad

Comment: FYI: The VSCode extension mentioned by Atul is called "CodeLLDB" in the VSCode Extensions Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1.) Remove the .vscode/launch.json file

2.) Go to the Run tab of VSCode and it will now give you a link to click called "create a launch.json file". Click it and choose "C++ (GDB/LLDB)".

3.) Now edit the "program" and "args" as described by Atul in his answer. The resulting launch.json will look something like this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/usr/local/homebrew/bin/node",
        "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/test/test_binding.js"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "MIMode": "lldb"
    }
]
```

4.) Test it out by dereferencing an invalid pointer in your C++ addon. VSCode will automatically break on the line that crashed.

Also, `brew install nodejs --with-debug` no longer works and is not needed.